# Level curves of function $f(x,y)=e^{xy}$

Tags: calculus

How can I find the level curves of function $f(x,y)=e^{xy}$?

I started with $f(x,y) = K$ ($K$ being a real number).

I already divided it inro three cases, when $k>1$, $k=1$ and $0<k<1$, but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $K>0\land K\ne 1$, the level set is the hyperbola $xy=\ln K$. For $K=1$ the level set is the pair of lines $xy=0$. For $K\le 0$ it's $\emptyset$.